# XDV condition based on a presence of a cookie

Tags: mobile, plone, xdv

I'd like to create XDV rules based on a cookie condition.

Let's say that I have a cookie called "mobile" and if it's present I want to delete some stylesheet and script rules.

(BTW prototyping plone.org mobile version)

Comment: Are you running xdv via collective.xdv or in some other process? xdv doesn't have this feature, but if you're applying the rules in nginx you might be able to accomplish something similar by choosing which xdv stylesheet to apply based on a cookie.

Comment: For the record, this is something that's very easily done with [Skinny]. Instead of applying transformations in the middle, Skinny provides an easy way of to develop a separate skin that uses ZPT and has full access to all of Plone and Zope's API (including request.cookie). We're using Skinny on vienna.info to serve a [separate mobile skin]. [Skinny]: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.skinny [separate mobile skin]: http://m.vienna.info/en

Comment: I specifically want to manipulate HTML itself. What would be the way to make XDV do this?

Comment: Also I cannot assume it is running collective.xdv - could be nginx or apache

Comment: I think we'd need to add a feature to XDV to inspect headers. You could then check the Cookie header, or maybe use nginx to set a custom header based on the presence of a cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDV / Diazo supports standard XSLT parameters, just add:

```
<xsl:param name="myvar">default value</xsl:param>
```

to the top level of your `<rules>` and you can then access the value using `$myvar` in if-content expressions.

Currently only Nginx provides a way to configure which parameters are passed in (see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xdv#nginx for an example where the $path parameter is passed in.)

The Apache mod_tansform module does not have parameter support. I had some half working code for it, but it needs to gain xpath quoting support and better configuration syntax before I can merge it into the distributed mod_transform.

I would like to see tal expression to parameter mapping in plone.app.theming (the next version of collective.xdv) but I don't know when I'll get to implement it. It should be fairly simple though.

For the record I'm strongly against adding xslt extensions that would allow inline tal in xpaths.

For this use case though, I do think it is better to have a separate web and mobile domain, as you indeed advocate at http://webandmobile.mfabrik.com/docs/web-and-mobile/user-manual/redirector ;)